# Can I use PostgreSQL 8.3.x for OpenStreetMap?

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, phppgadmin

I'm trying to install phpPgAdmin as an XAMPP addon when I encountered an error because the latest phpPgAdmin supports upto PostgreSQL version 8.3.x. So I decided to install PostgreSQL 8.3.11 instead of the latest (PGSQL 8.4.x). Will this matter to my OSM application? Thanks!

Comment: What is "an error" ? And why don't you use a real tool like pgAdmin3 ? A PHP-script can be nice, but it's very limited in it's usage when you compare it with tools like pgAdmin3.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of advantages to Postgres 8.4 over 8.3, and Open Street Map / PostGIS should work on it, so I'd recommend using 8.4 for the Postgres version, and instead grabbing the latest version of phpPgAdmin from the projects github repo (http://github.com/xzilla/phppgadmin), which fully supports 8.4. That will tide you over until the next official phpPgAdmin release, which is scheduled to happen in the next few weeks.

Answer (score 0):

The only link between OSM and postgresql is probably postgis.

Postgis lastest version (1.5.1) requires postgresql >= 8.3, so the answer is ***no, it won't matter*** - if, of course, I understood your question correctly.